# Google+ Sign-In button deployed, can a page restrict access without a server $_SESSION?

Tags: google-plus, google-api-client

Say the page where user can update his own profile: `profile_update.php?id=1234567`...(user's Google id).

Question:

How can I restrict access with the returned `authResult` or `me`? (I mean which item in the object will help that, not how to get these item out).

or Do I still need to build a server side `$_SESSION` for that?

Answer (score 1):

You could do some validation on the client side using the auth result, but you'd also want to verify that the request you get on the server side is from who you think it is from to prevent cross-site request forgery attacks. So you'd need something that validate that the POST that update the profile came from an authenticated user, not just that the POST data was in the correct format. So typically, your form will send a specific code (a CSRF token) and that same token must be present in the user's cookies (or a server side session token, which in PHP can be accessed via $_SESSION).